# Getting out of Emergency Shell after fsck failure

Tags: arch-linux, fsck

After re-arranging some hard drives across my SATA ports (this is a desktop machine), I get the following error after trying to boot up Arch:

[image: Error]

What could have caused this? Did I accidentally turn off the machine while it was writing to the SSD disk? How do I escape this?

Comment: what do you mean with **"After re-arranging some hard drives across my SATA ports "**? you changed order of disk in SATA ports?

Comment: I plugged in an additional SATA drive and re-arranged the ports.  I just figured out that if I remove the additional drive, my system boots as usual. I think the drive names sda and sdb were getting switched, and it was causing me to not to boot. This is weird though since my /etc/fstab locates drives on the basis of UUIIDs. So now I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Change the boot order of the disks in your bios.

Answer (score 0):

Start a live-CD (I like [grml](https://grml.org/), but there a lots of others) and check the file system on /dev/sda2 with fsck.